# How to write to a non-writeable field such as formula fields or CreatedDate during unit tests?

Tags: apex, unit-test, sobject

**TL;DR**

How can I write to non-writeable SObject fields while running apex unit tests?

**Background**

While creating unit tests that check a method's functionality independent of any DML functions, it is sometimes necessary (or at least very helpful) to set field values on SObjects.

*Example:*

Lets say I have the class shown below. (In this example, my org's `Account` object has a formula field `Owners_Email_Address__c` which, returns the email address of the Owner of the Account.)

```
public with sharing class MyClass{

    public static String getParentAccountsOwnerEmail(Contact myContact){
        return (String)myContact.Account.get('Owners_Email_Address__c');
    }

    public static Boolean createdDateMatchesValue(Contact myContact, Date expectedCreatedDate){
        return myContact.CreatedDate == expectedCreatedDate;
    }
}
```

While writing my apex class, I could get both the `Owners_Email_Address__c` and `CreatedDate` values populated, but doing so would require multiple DML operations:

- create and insert User for Account owner
- create and insert Account with new User as Owner
- create and insert Contact then use `Test.setCreatedDate()` to specify a date (if something different than the current date needed)

While this is all fine, it often runs into other issues that cause additional considerations and overhead, such as:

- Making sure other required field on each desired record to insert are properly set
- Verifying that a desired field wasn't changed during the DML operation due to another automation

As an org grows and its automations grow, this can make inserting just a few records for a test quite a headache.

**Question**

When DML operations aren't necessary for a test (such as when building unit tests that should only test the functionality of a specific function), how can I bypass the need to have multiple DML operations to populate non-writeable fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SObject record with specified read-only field values using `JSON.deserialize()`, as long as you do not need to actually run any DML statements (insert, update, delete) on those records.

The setup for this will follow something like this:

`MySObjectType myRecord = (MySObjectType) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, MySObjectType.class);`

And your `jsonString` will look something like this:

`'{"attributes":{"type":"MySObjectType"},"My_Read_Only_Field":"My test-desired value"}'`

An example from the question:

```
String desiredEmail = 'fakeEmail@fakemail.com';
String accountString = '{"attributes":{"type":"Account"},"Owners_Email_Address__c":"'+desiredEmail+'", "CreatedDate" : "2000-01-01"}';
Account testAccount = (Account) JSON.deserialize(accountString, Account.class);

// These should both pass
Assert.areEqual(desiredEmail, testAccount.Owners_Email_Address__c);
Assert.areEqual(Date.newInstance(2000, 1, 1), testAccount.CreatedDate);
```

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) for a clean API that uses this technique under the hood, as mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321894/50252).